# How can i add strings to an empty variable to make a long word?

Tags: python, string, variables, addition

so.. i want to put all the objects in the list together, and my idea was to create a variable with nothing in it and make a for loop to add the strings to the variable... but it doesn't work :( any help?

I searched for an answer but could not find anything online... I am very noob, so sorry if am wrong.

```
sounds = ["super", "cali", "fragil", "istic", "expi", "ali", "docious"]
x=""
for s in sounds:
    x+s
print(x)
```

I expected x to be "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious" at the end.

Comment: `''.join(sounds)`

Comment: You probably forgot an *equal* sign: `x += s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join`:

```
sounds = ["super", "cali", "fragil", "istic", "expi", "ali", "docious"]

x = "".join(sounds)

print(x)
```

As for your solution, you're missing a `=`:

```
sounds = ["super", "cali", "fragil", "istic", "expi", "ali", "docious"]
x=""
for s in sounds:
    x += s
print(x)
```

You get the same thing:

```
supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
```

Comment: yeah...that is very useful... but I wonder why the strings cannot be attached to the variable.

Comment: now i get it... thanks, it was only the +=... sorry :)